# How can I charge number line of dropdownmenu using @shoutem/ui?

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I try to used @shoutem/ui! In my project, I define 1 Component with header is NavigationBar of @shoutem/ui, in NavigationBar I try define rightComponent is an DropDownMenu, but when long content, navigation bar will made 2 line and I don't want that way! I'm still want it pingleline!

That's what I'm facing:

[image]

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this PR https://github.com/shoutem/ui/pull/216/files solves it, so please check if you are using the latest version of @shoutem/ui.